# TextWatcher: NullPointerException

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

I am trying to change the value of one editview while there is change in another editview even if the program runs value is not passed to editview.Value is passes from one edit view to another and then the value is multiplied by parsed value. help my main activity code is:

```
public class Main extends ListActivity {
public double C_webuserDouble;
public double C_cashDouble;
public double C_transferDouble;

public double S_webuserDouble;
public double S_cashDouble;
public double S_transferDouble;

EditText resultTxt ;
TextView cashTxtView ;
TextView webuserTxtView;
TextView transferTxtView;
TextView S_cashTxtView ;
TextView S_webuserTxtView;
TextView S_transferTxtView;


/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.listplaceholder);

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();


    JSONObject json = JSONfunctions.getJSONfromURL("http://ldsclient.com/ftp/strtojson.php");

    try{

        JSONArray  netfoxlimited = json.getJSONArray("netfoxlimited");

        for(int i=0;i<netfoxlimited.length();i++){                      
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();    
            JSONObject e = netfoxlimited.getJSONObject(i);

            map.put("date",  e.getString("date"));
            map.put("c_web", e.getString("c_web"));
            map.put("c_bank",e.getString("c_bank"));
            map.put("c_cash",  e.getString("c_cash"));
            map.put("s_web",   e.getString("s_web"));
            map.put("s_bank",e.getString("s_bank"));
            map.put("s_cash", e.getString("s_cash"));
            mylist.add(map);        

        /** C_webuserDouble=json.getDouble("c_web");
            C_transferDouble= json.getDouble("c_bank");
            C_cashDouble=json.getDouble("c_cash");


            S_webuserDouble=json.getDouble("s_web");
            S_transferDouble= json.getDouble("s_bank");
            S_cashDouble=json.getDouble("s_cash");*/

        }       
    }catch(JSONException e)        {
         Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
    }

    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, mylist , R.layout.main, 
                    new String[] {"date", "c_web" ,"c_bank","c_cash","s_web" ,"s_bank","s_cash",}, 
                    new int[] { R.id.item_title,R.id.webuserTxtView, R.id.transferTxtView, R.id.cashTxtView, R.id.S_webuserTxtView, R.id.S_transferTxtView, R.id.S_cashTxtView});

    setListAdapter(adapter);
    resultTxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    resultTxt.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            String text;
            text=resultTxt.getText().toString();
            if(resultTxt.getText().length()>0){
calculateSum(C_webuserDouble,C_cashDouble,C_transferDouble);
                    calculateSunrise(S_webuserDouble,S_cashDouble,S_transferDouble);
            }

}

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1,
                int arg2, int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }});}

private void calculateSum(Double webuserDouble, Double cashDouble, Double transferDouble){

    String Qty;
    Qty= resultTxt.getText().toString();



    if(Qty.length() >0){
    double QtyValue = Double.parseDouble(Qty);
    double cashResult;
    double webuserResult;
    double transferResult;

    cashResult =  cashDouble * QtyValue;
    webuserResult = webuserDouble * QtyValue;
    transferResult = transferDouble * QtyValue;

    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
    String cashResultStr = df.format(cashResult);
    String webuserResultStr = df.format(webuserResult);
    String transferResultStr = df.format(transferResult);

    cashTxtView.setText(String.valueOf(cashResultStr));
    webuserTxtView.setText(String.valueOf(webuserResultStr));
    transferTxtView.setText(String.valueOf(transferResultStr));


    //cashTxtView.setFilters(new InputFilter[] {new DecimalDigitsInputFilter(2)});
}

    if(Qty.length()==0){
        cashTxtView.setText(String.valueOf(cashDouble));
        webuserTxtView.setText(String.valueOf(webuserDouble));
        transferTxtView.setText(String.valueOf(transferDouble));

    }

}

private void calculateSunrise(Double webuserDouble, Double cashDouble, Double transferDouble){

String Qty;
    Qty= resultTxt.getText().toString();



    if(Qty.length() >0){
    double QtyValue = Double.parseDouble(Qty);
    double cashResult;
    double webuserResult;
    double transferResult;

    cashResult =  cashDouble * QtyValue;
    webuserResult = webuserDouble * QtyValue;
    transferResult = transferDouble * QtyValue;

    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
    String cashResultStr = df.format(cashResult);
    String webuserResultStr = df.format(webuserResult);
    String transferResultStr = df.format(transferResult);

    S_cashTxtView.setText(String.valueOf(cashResultStr));
    S_webuserTxtView.setText(String.valueOf(webuserResultStr));
    S_transferTxtView.setText(String.valueOf(transferResultStr));
    }

    if(Qty.length()==0){
        S_cashTxtView.setText(String.valueOf(cashDouble));
        S_webuserTxtView.setText(String.valueOf(webuserDouble));
        S_transferTxtView.setText(String.valueOf(transferDouble));

    }

 }


}
```

Following is my listplaceholder code

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">    

<ListView
    android:id="@id/android:list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="false" />

<TextView
    android:id="@id/android:empty"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="No data"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

all the code are same but following logcat error generates when user  input is given

```
08-29 14:53:01.234: E/AndroidRuntime(2206): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
08-29 14:53:01.245: E/AndroidRuntime(2206): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-29 14:53:01.245: E/AndroidRuntime(2206):     at com.mokshya.jsonnetfoxtab.Main.calculateSum(Main.java:142)
08-29 14:53:01.245: E/AndroidRuntime(2206):     at com.mokshya.jsonnetfoxtab.Main.access$0(Main.java:120)
08-29 14:53:01.245: E/AndroidRuntime(2206):     at com.mokshya.jsonnetfoxtab.Main$1.afterTextChanged(Main.java:101)
```

Comment: Please, show this line: com.mokshya.jsonnetfoxtab.Main.onCreate(Main.java:108)

Comment: Textwatcher is not the issue here...

Comment: NullPointerException problem on Main.java at line 108. can you please provide line 108 code here.

Comment: Line 108 is the issue :)

Comment: Line 108 code is  resultTxt.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){
public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
    calculateSum(C_webuserDouble,C_cashDouble,C_transferDouble);
    calculateSunrise(S_webuserDouble,S_cashDouble,S_transferDouble);
   }

Comment: Did you checked that component is not null? resultTxt

Comment: resultTxt is not empty. It is EditText where i am asking user to input the value

Comment: I know what is an EditText. But it could be the findViewById returns null.

Comment: findViewById takes the value what is inserted in editText1 and passes to resultTxt

Comment: can you please provide you "listplaceholder" xml

Comment: @mishu Cn i have posted line 108 code

Comment: @sur007: no that is not how findViewById works. The function binds the component from your xml layout to your java attribute. To return the user input you have to call resultTxt.getText().toString().

Comment: @sur007 use <EditText
    android:id="@id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="No data"/> or <AutoCompleteTextView
    android:id="@id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="No data"/> in your xml textfield

Comment: @MishuCn cwhere should i put this code resultTxt.getText().toString()

Comment: @sur007: it should be in listplaceholder the field where you are retrieving your text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your xml to that

```
<TextView     
android:id="@+id/editText1     
android:layout_width="fill_parent"     
android:layout_height="wrap_content"     
android:text="No data"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

according to your programming listplaceholder code should like this

```
<ListView
android:id="@id/listview1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:drawSelectorOnTop="false" />

<EditText
android:id="@id/editText1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="No data"/>
```

OR

```
<ListView
android:id="@id/listview1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:drawSelectorOnTop="false" />

<AutoCompleteTextView
android:id="@id/editText1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="No data"/>
```

In programming

change here

```
 ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, mylist , R.layout.main, 
                new String[] {"date", "c_web" ,"c_bank","c_cash","s_web" ,"s_bank","s_cash",}, 
                new int[] { R.id.item_title,R.id.webuserTxtView, R.id.transferTxtView, R.id.cashTxtView, R.id.S_webuserTxtView, R.id.S_transferTxtView, R.id.S_cashTxtView});


ListView listView = ( ListView ) findViewById(R.id.listview1);

// Setting the adapter to the listView
 listView.setAdapter(adapter);

 resultTxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
 /// and so on
```

Comment: i did this but when i provide input the program gets crashed

Comment: i have done all editing but now there's NullPointException error and is on this line resultTxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        resultTxt.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){

Comment: i have also used textwatcher but my code working fine. Normally this kind of NullPointException error happen cause of you want to retrieve a data from a field which was not declared. does your application run? i mean when your application crash? after typing something in textfield?

Comment: OK then can you provide me some link to tutorial defining how to work on textwatcher

Comment: http://www.cybernetikz.com/blog/android/android-textwatcher-example/  here i create a simple example please check if it help

Comment: thanx buddy it was not solved so i m trying another simple one i'll watch this ASAP i done with this(i am doin layout right now)